# WorkFlowDefination not Found in Elsa 2.4 Version

Tags: elsa-workflows

I am new in Elsa .net library.

I have define one Activity in which i have to define input paramater for the activity

like below way as document saw in version 1 :

```
 public WorkflowExpression<string> UserId {
            get => GetState<WorkflowExpression<string>>();
            set => SetState(value);
        }
```

but it give me error that `The type or namespace could not found`

as i don't know can somebody help me with this.

I read the whole documentation nothing will define this.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just getting started with Elsa, then please make sure to use Elsa 2, since Elsa 1 isn't supported anymore.

With Elsa 2, you can define your activity input as follows:

```cs
[ActivityInput] public string UserId { get; set; }
```

For more information, make sure to checkout the [documentation about activity properties](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/docs/next/extensibility/extensibility-custom-activities#properties).